# When I create a 'single vert' object and add a 'skin modifier". I cant edit it

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode

When I create a skin modifier. I can't edit the faces, vertices, or edges. None of them even show up when I select it.

[image: In edit mode but cant edit]

Comment: you need to apply the modifier if you want to be able to edit the generated faces

Comment: In Blender, when you go into edit mode you always go back to editing the underlying base mesh, before the modifiers do their thing. If you want to edit the result of the modifier you have to "apply" the modifier (this option is found in the drop-down menu next to the modifier's name). But keep in mind that applying a modifier 'bakes' it to the mesh, so you can't change the modifier's settings anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### When using the Skin Modifier on a single vertex...

It is common to use the Skin Modifier on what begins as a single vertex mesh. There are a few "gotchas" to look out for that can make this workflow confusing the first time you try it.

**Add > Mesh > Single Vert** does not automatically switch you into **Vertex Selection Mode** (although maybe it should). Anyway, first make sure you can select your single vert by switching to this mode.

[image]

Note that the **Skin Modifier** is unique in that if you duplicate or add new islands of geometry, their "skin" won't be generated until you select a vertex and click the `Mark Root` button on the modifier. Each island of the mesh needs to have a "root" vertex.

[image]

If you want to change the thickness of the "skin" that is generated from a given vertex or multiple vertices, select them, then adjust the **Vertex Radius** sliders (**X** and **Y**) that can be found in the **Item** tab under the **Transform** collapsible menu.

[image]

**Tip:** You can click-drag down on Radius X so that your selection also covers the Radius Y slider. Then you can adjust both sliders at the same time.

**Note:** If "Nothing selected" appears under Transform, you may have hidden your single vert, and not have realized it because the Object Origin is blocking your view. If so, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to un-hide it.

Finally, as others have mentioned, if you want to edit the modifier result (the skin that is generated), you must first **Apply** the modifier. This is a destructive edit, so consider saving your work first.

Answer (score 1):

press E and extrude the vert.
skin modifier needs edges .
if you want do edit the computation result of the modifier,
you need to apply the modifier first.

Comment: Thank you so much